# Close programmatically all cell groups in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to collapse all cell groups in the current notebook? I tried

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellGroup]
FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
```

but nothing changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
```

Or:

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "SelectAll"]]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
```

The token may be found in [Tokens Related to the Cell Menu](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CellTokens.html) in the help browser.

This specific operation may be found under the [**Scope** section of the `FrontEndToken` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrontEndToken.html#33028262).

Comment: Note that "OpenCloseGroup" and "SelectionCloseAllGroups" work differently when you have nested cell groups.

Comment: @Brett the OP asked to "collapse all cell groups" -- isn't that what `"SelectionCloseAllGroups"` does?

Comment: And yet the sample code used `"OpenCloseGroup"`.  But the OP might not have been aware of the differences between them.

Comment: @Brett Okay.  I thought you were politely trying to tell me my answer was wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard is it possible to only close or open one level deep?

Comment: @chris there is the token `"OpenCloseGroup"` which performs the same action as `Ctrl`+`'` -- does that do what you want?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard exactly! I only knew of Crl+{ or Crl+} Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "OpenCloseGroup"]
```

although it only works if the notebook starts with a cell group, and not with a lone cell.  (The menu item behaves the same way.)

If you know there are `cellGroupCount` groups, you could also do something like:

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook]
Do[SelectionMove[nb, Next, CellGroup];
 FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "OpenCloseGroup"], {cellGroupCount}]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dependance on the notebook start, that clarifies things