# Print documentation (or front end) with all Openers open?

Tags: front-end, documentation, interactive

From the online reference:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Opener.html

a JS function javascript:open_ES() is invoked to open all Openers within a section. Note (1) this feature is absent in the built-in MMA documentation center; (2) even online it selectively opens the EXAMPLES section (for Opener).

Often I need to quickly overview all the sections including More Information, Options, Properties & Relations &c.

Is there a way to program the documentation or even the Front End that contains Opener and Toggler to map them all to True? Perhaps a palette selection.

Comment: What is this [tag:interactive] tag? I am inclined to merge it with [tag:dynamic]...

Comment: Feel free - I think it was pre-existing, didn't mean to create it if I did.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6809/121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to do this programmatically I suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

If you *do* need to do this programmatically please provide some context for the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wizard, that'll do.. Do you know that WRI tech support couldn't come up with that solution? Tech is getting so complex with so many features and internal state that they don't even have a KB with full coverage on such issue.

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm glad this was helpful.  Also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6809/121).